# How to run Python script before each build in Xcode?

Tags: python, xcode

I'm trying to run a simple Python script every time I build my app in Xcode. The Python script is called `test.py` and resides in my project folder as a sibling to my `.xcodeproj` file.

I think I followed the instructions in the Stack Overflow post
[Is this possible to run a python script before Xcode doing compiling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989841/is-this-possible-to-run-a-python-script-before-xcode-doing-compiling) but I am receiving the error `Shell Script Invocation Error: Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1`

I installed [Python 3.5.2](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-352/), but when I type `python -V` into Terminal I get `Python 2.7.10`. However, when I type `python3 -V` into Terminal I get `Python 3.6.0`. Typing `which python` into Terminal returns `/usr/bin/python`, while typing `which python3` into Terminal returns `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3`.

Following the instructions in [Xcode: Running a script before every build that modifies source code directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976454/xcode-running-a-script-before-every-build-that-modifies-source-code-directly) I also moved the Run Script section in Build Phases to before Compile Sources.

This is what my Run Script section looks like. I have a strong feeling that the fix is annoyingly simple but have been unsuccessful trying to figure out what I am doing wrong / what search terms to use in Google or Stack Overflow.

[image: Run Script – Build Phases]

And of course, let me know what other info I can provide to help debug.

**EDIT:** I have no preference for which version of Python I use other than that it allows me to run a Python script each time I build. I just installed Python 3.5.2 because I thought it might help.

**EDIT 2:** Tried deleting Derived Data (even though I am using [Xcode 8.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006464/how-to-fix-the-issue-command-bin-sh-failed-with-exit-code-1-in-iphone)) in addition to `Clean` (Cmd-Shift-K) and `Cleaning Build Folder...` (Cmd-Shift-Alt-K) and still no luck.

Comment: If you want Python3.5, you need to run `python3.5` on the command line instead of `python3` which runs the last version of Python 3, which is Python 3.6.0 on your installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get this working by using `/bin/sh` as my shell and `python test.py` as my script.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Shell" input, try this path: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5'